# How to evaluate an expression in nim?

Tags: macros, metaprogramming, nim-lang

I'm trying to perform the equivalent of the `eval` method from Python in nim.
I was under the impression that `parseStmt` from the `macros` package should help me with this, but I'm facing a compilation issue that I don't understand.

```
import macros

echo parseStmt("1 + 2")
```

I would have expected this to print `3` when executed, but instead the compilation complains that

```
Error: request to generate code for .compileTime proc: $
```

I found [this thread](https://forum.nim-lang.org/t/2253), and the examples there work, and following this, I was able to make the following program that works as I would expect:

```
import macros
import strformat

macro eval(value: string): untyped =
  result = parseStmt fmt"{value}"

echo eval("1+2")
```

But I don't undertand why it needs to be written in this way at all. If I inline the statement, `let value = "1 + 2"; echo parseStmt fmt"{value}"`, I get the same compile error as above.

Also, why is `parseStmt value` different from `parseStmt fmt"{value}"`, in the context of the `eval` macro above?

What am I missing here?

Thank you in advance for any clarifications!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Unlike Python which is an interpreted language, Nim is compiled. This means that all code is parsed and turned into machine code on compile-time and the program that you end up with doesn't really know anything about Nim at all (at least as long as you don't import the Nim compiler as a module, which is possible). So `parseStmt` and all macro/template expansion stuff in Nim is done completely during compilation. The error, although maybe a bit hard to read, is trying to tell you that what was passed to `$` (which is the convert-to-string operator in Nim, and called by `echo` on all its arguments) is a compile-time thing that can't be used on runtime. In this case it's because `parseStmt` doesn't return `"3"`, it returns something like `NimNode(kind: nnkIntLit, intVal: 3)`, and the `NimNode` type is only available during compile-time. Nim however allows you to run code on compile-time to return other code, this is what a macro does. The `eval` macro you wrote there takes `value` which is any statement that resolves to a string during runtime, passed as a `NimNode`. This is also why `result = parseStmt value` won't work in your case, because `value` is not yet a string, but could be something like reading a string from standard input which would result in a string during runtime. However the use of `strformat` here is a bit confusing and overkill. If you change your code to:

```
import macros

macro eval(value: static[string]): untyped =
  result = parseStmt value

echo eval("1+2")
```

It will work just fine. This is because we have now told Nim that `value` needs to be a `static` i.e. known during compile-time. In this case the string literal `"1+2"` is obviously known at compile-time, but this could also be a call to a compile-time procedure, or even the output of `staticRead` which reads a file during compilation.

As you can see Nim is very powerful, but the barrier between compile-time and run-time can sometimes be a bit confusing. Note also that your `eval` procedure doesn't actually evaluate anything at compile-time, it simply returns the Nim code `1 + 2` so your code ends up being `echo 1 + 2`. If you want to actually run the code at compile-time you might want to look into compile-time procedures.

Hope this helps shed some light on your issue.

Answer (score 2):

Note: while this answer outlines *why* this happens, keep in mind that what you're trying to do probably won't result in what you want (which I assumed to be runtime evaluation of expressions).

You're trying to pass a `NimNode` to `parseStmt` which expects a `string`. The `fmt` macro automatically stringifies anything in the `{}`, you can omit the `fmt` by doing `$value` to turn the node into a string.

As I already noted, this *will not* work as it does in Python: Nim does not have runtime evaluation. The expression in the string is going to be evaluated at compile time, so a simple example like this will *not* do what you want:

```
import std/rdstdin
let x = readLineFromStdin(">")
echo eval(x)
```

#### Why?

First of all, because you're stringifying the AST you pass to the `eval`, it's not the `string` behind the `x` variable that's going to get passed to the macro - it's going to be the symbol that denotes the `x` variable. If you stringify a symbol, you get the underlying identifier, which means that `parseStmt` will receive `"x"` as its parameter. This will effect in the string stored in `x` being printed out, which is wrong.

What you want instead is the following:

```
import std/rdstdin
import std/macros

macro eval(value: static string): untyped =
  result = parseStmt(value)

echo eval("1 + 2")
```

This prevents runtime-known values from being passed to the macro. You can only pass `const`s and literals to it now, which is the correct behavior.